# pygit2 Slow performance on Diff Patch iteration and no cache on DiffStats

Tags: git-diff, libgit2, pygit2

It seems, *pygit2* is not caching Patch and *DiffStats* attributes from a *Diff* object.
Each access to these attributes re-triggers the git stats calculation. Is there a way to optimize this operation and possibly cache the stats numbers?

I compared the Diff operation on a large commit using GitPthon and pygit2 and the difference in time to generate was substantial.

Here is an example displaying performances of *GitPython* vs *GitPython* git diff and stats (several times slower using pygit2):

```
import os
import string
import random
import tempfile
from time import time
import pygit2
import git as gitpython

repo_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
pygit2_repo = pygit2.init_repository(path=repo_dir.name, bare=False, initial_head='master')
gitpython_repo = gitpython.Repo(repo_dir.name)


def create_commit(repo, nb_files=20, nb_lines=100000, nb_char_per_line=50):
    for x in range(nb_files):
        blob = '\n'.join([''.join(random.choices(string.printable, k=nb_char_per_line))] * nb_lines)
        with open(os.path.join(repo.workdir, 'file_%s.txt' % x), 'w') as f:
            f.write(blob)
    repo.index.add_all()
    repo.index.write()
    tree = repo.index.write_tree()

    parents = []
    if not repo.is_empty:
        parent, ref = repo.resolve_refish(refish=repo.head.name)
        parents = [parent.oid]

    return repo.create_commit("HEAD", repo.default_signature, repo.default_signature, "Commit message", tree, parents).hex


if __name__ == '__main__':
    first_commit = create_commit(pygit2_repo)
    second_commit = create_commit(pygit2_repo)

    t0 = time()
    pygit2_commit = pygit2_repo.get(second_commit)
    pygit2_diff = pygit2_repo.diff(first_commit, second_commit)
    print('pygit2    diff generation  %f' % (time()-t0))

    t0 = time()
    gitpython_commit = gitpython_repo.commit(second_commit)
    gitpython_diff = gitpython_commit.diff(gitpython_commit.parents[0])
    print('gitpython diff generation  %f' % (time()-t0))

    t0 = time()
    s = pygit2_diff.stats
    pygit2_total_deletions = s.deletions
    pygit2_total_insertions = s.insertions
    print('pygit2    stats lookup  %f' % (time()-t0))

    t0 = time()
    gitpython_total_deletions = gitpython_commit.stats.total['deletions']
    gitpython_total_insertions = gitpython_commit.stats.total['insertions']
    print('gitpython stats lookup  %f' % (time()-t0))

    t0 = time()
    pygit2_line_stats = {patch.delta.new_file.path: patch.line_stats for patch in pygit2_diff}
    print('pygit2    line stats  %f' % (time()-t0))

    t0 = time()
    gitpython_line_stats = gitpython_commit.stats.files
    print('gitpython line stats  %f' % (time()-t0))

    t0 = time()
    pygit2_diff_changes = [(d.new_file.path, d.old_file.path) for d in pygit2_diff.deltas]
    print('pygit2    diff deltas iteration   %f' % (time()-t0))

    t0 = time()
    gitpython_diff_changes = [(patch.a_path, patch.b_path) for patch in gitpython_diff]
    print('gitpython diff changes iteration  %f' % (time()-t0))
```

There is also the odd behavior of recalculating all changes when iterating over files from a *Diff* object.

Is it possible to pre-populate all changes within a Diff to improve speed?

On another aspect, is it possible to discard certain file differences at the *git* level when their changes are too excessive, possibly given an argument given to the *diff* function?

Thanks in advance!